# IMEI number got changed

Tags: imei

I have given my moto g(2nd gen) for sim slot replacement as it as not working and it was under warranty period but then they have changed my IMEI no as well. Do i need to worry about it??

Answer (score -1):

No you don't.... There's actually no problem, if you don't feel very comfortable with the new IMEI, you can always change it yourself using the engineering mode.

Comment: What? Changing IMEI is illegal in several countries.

Comment: How can I change my IMEI on my GT-I9505?